# Pendulums in inertial and non-inertial frames

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

If I have a non-inertial frame accelerating with acceleration $A$ with respect to an inertial frame and if I have two pendulums, one in the inertial frame and the other in the non inertial frame, then how will the motion of the pendulum differ when seen from each frame? The pendulum in the inertial frame should oscillate about the vertical and the pendulum in the non-inertial frame should oscillate about an angle $\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{A}{g}\right)$ with the vertical. I think both observers should agree with that? But if I represent the coordinates in the inertial frame as unprimed coordinates and the coordinates in the non-inertial frame as primed coordinates then I have
$$a' = a - A$$
which means that the two observers should disagree about the angular acceleration $\ddot{\theta}$ which depends on the tangential acceleration of the pendulums. But do they really disagree? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The question as posed, doesn't really make sense. In an inertial frame, a pendulum won't oscillate at all, as there is no 'g-force' in any direction.

Comment: Sorry, by an inertial frame I meant something stationary on the surface of the Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The EOM's

with $x'=v(\tau)\,\tau+x$ where $v(\tau)$ is the velocity between $x'$ and $x$

you obtain the kinetic energy and the potential energy of a pendulum that move in the prime system.

Pendulum position vector

$$\vec{R}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} v \left( \tau \right) \tau+L\sin \left( 
\varphi  \right) \\L\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

thus:

Kinetic energy

$$T=\frac{m}{2}\vec{\dot{R}}\cdot\vec{\dot{R}} $$

Potential Energy

$$U=-m\,g\,L\cos(\phi)$$

and the  the equation of motion

$$\ddot{\varphi}+{\frac {g\sin \left( \varphi  \right) }{L}}+{\frac {\cos \left( 
\varphi  \right)  \left( {\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}v \left( \tau
 \right)  \right) \tau+2\,\cos \left( \varphi  \right) {\frac {d}{d
\tau}}v \left( \tau \right) }{L}}=0
\tag 1$$

with $v(\tau)=-v_0-\frac{1}{2}\,A\,\tau\quad$ in equation (1)

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}\varphi  \left( \tau \right) +{\frac {\sin
 \left( \varphi  \left( \tau \right)  \right) g}{L}}-\,{\frac {\cos
 \left( \varphi  \left( \tau \right)  \right) A}{L}}
=0\tag 2$$

**Simulation**

[image]

Thus:

The acceleration parameter $A$ dose't
affected the frequency ,$\omega=\sqrt{g/L}$ of the pendulum, which is the same for the $x,y$  space.  the amplitude of $\varphi(\tau)$ is proportional to the  acceleration parameter $A$.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be $x' = x - v(0)t - \frac{1}{2}at^2$ ? If I sub $v(t) = v(0) + at$ in your equation I don't get the same form.

Comment: I also find your conclusion troubling because both observers should agree on the time period and hence the frequency regardless of whether the oscillation angle is small or not. Because t' = t in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient I did some modifications

Comment: But why isn't $x' = x - v(0)t - \frac{1}{2}At^2$ ?

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient $x=v(t)*t$

Comment: don't you mean $x' = x - \int v(t)dt$

Comment: I didn’t use x’ instead I  used v(t)*t , so with proper v(t) you get the same result

Comment: Look at the position vector